# Is color undefined

Tags: color, conditionals

I want to check whether a color has been previously defined, consider the below code which doesn't execute.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\colorprovide}[2]{\ifx\undefined{#1}\colorlet{#1}{#2}\fi}

\begin{document}
    %Initial Definition
    \colorprovide{mycolor}{red}
    \textcolor{mycolor}{Test 1}

    %Will overwrite
    \colorlet{mycolor}{green}
    \textcolor{mycolor}{Test 2}

    %Should NOT overwrite as it exists
    \colorprovide{mycolor}{red}
    \textcolor{mycolor}{Test 3}
\end{document}
```

In other words and analogous to `\providecommand{...}` not renewing an existing command if it exists, I need a macro which will will **NOT** redefine a color if the color has already been defined.

The above code throws an error as the logical checking part `\ifx\undefined...` is incorrect.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After `\definecolor{foo}{<model>}{<spec>}` or `\colorlet{foo}{<color>}`, the new color specification is store in a macro called

```
\\color@foo
```

(with a backslash in the name). You accomplish your wish with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\colorprovide}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{\string\color@#1}{\colorlet{#1}{#2}}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%Initial Definition
\colorprovide{mycolor}{red}
\textcolor{mycolor}{Test 1}

%Will overwrite
\colorlet{mycolor}{blue}
\textcolor{mycolor}{Test 2}

%Should NOT overwrite as it exists
\colorprovide{mycolor}{red}
\textcolor{mycolor}{Test 3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Addition suggested by H. Oberdiek

Actually `xcolor` already defines a check, but doesn't provide a “public version”:

```
\def\@ifundefinedcolor#1{\@ifundefined{\string\color@#1}}
```

so you can say

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\colorprovide}[2]{%
  \@ifundefinedcolor{#1}{\colorlet{#1}{#2}}{}}
\makeatother
```

which is probably clearer and doesn't rely on the internal implementation of the macro holding the color specification.

Comment: Cheers. My wish is now accomplished....

Comment: Since version 2005/11/12 v2.07 package `xcolor` also defines `\@ifundefinedcolor` (with the same implementation as in your answer).

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but the only answer do not mention `\providecolor` that is available in `xcolor` since version 2.0 (2004/07/04).

This command has three parameters and in this particular case one can use it as `\providecolor{<color to provide>}{named}{<existing color>}`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\colorprovide}[2]{\providecolor{#1}{named}{#2}}

\begin{document}
  %Initial Definition
  \colorprovide{mycolor}{red}
  \textcolor{mycolor}{Test 1}

  %Will overwrite
  \colorlet{mycolor}{green}
  \textcolor{mycolor}{Test 2}

  %Should NOT overwrite as it exists
  \colorprovide{mycolor}{red}
  \textcolor{mycolor}{Test 3}
\end{document}
```

[image]