# xcolor (TikZ): How to create a function 'ifcolorexists'

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, conditionals

I have defined eight colors (stepcolor0,...,stepcolor7).

Now I could have a list with more than 8 color-bearers. 
So I could need something like a function 
"`\ifcolorexists{stepcolor22}{stepcolor22}{black}`"

What do I have to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\foreach \N/\n in {0/brown, 1/red!70, 2/orange, 3/yellow!80!orange, 
4/green!70!black, 5/blue!50, 6/violet!60, 
7/gray}{    \xglobal\colorlet{stepcolor\N}{\n}      }

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {0,...,7}{%
\tikz[] \node[fill=stepcolor\n, label=below:{stepcolor\n}]{};
}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Endnumber{7} % works
%\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Endnumber{10} % works not

\foreach \n in {0,...,\Endnumber}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text=stepcolor\n] {S\n};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119059/is-color-undefined) post seems to be what you are looking for:

As far as I got your point.... This code could help you :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\foreach \N/\n in {0/brown, 1/red!70, 2/orange, 3/yellow!80!orange, 
4/green!70!black, 5/blue!50, 6/violet!60, 
7/gray}{    \xglobal\colorlet{stepcolor\N}{\n}      }

\makeatletter
\def\IsColorDefined#1{\@ifundefined{\string\color@#1}{black}{#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {0,...,7}{%
\tikz[] \node[fill=stepcolor\n, label=below:{stepcolor\n}]{};
}



%\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Endnumber{7} % works
%\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Endnumber{10} % works mot
\xdef\Endloop{0}
\foreach \n in {0,...,1000}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text=\IsColorDefined{stepcolor\n}] {S\n};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thats good. But I meant that if the colors are not defined, a default color is used, e.g. black

Comment: @cis ... Fixed to your requirement....

Comment: Ah, very good. Helps me a lot. :)

Comment: Thanks @cis ... Happy TeXing...